# How to choose if a new cluster is needed for an AWS Fargate Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a cluster with a mixture of services running on EC2 and Fargate, all being used internally. I am looking to deploy a new Fargate Service which is going to be publicly available over the Internet and will get around 5000 requests per minutes.

What factors do I need to consider so that I can choose if a new cluster should be created or if I can reuse the existing one? Would sharing of clusters also lead to security issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your deployment is purely using Fargate, not EC2, then there's really no technical reason to split it into a separate ECS cluster, but there's also no reason to keep it in the same cluster. There's no added cost to create a new Fargate cluster, and logically separating your services into separate ECS clusters can help you monitor them separately in CloudWatch.

Comment: This makes me wonder why AWS decided to even have a cluster associated with a Fargate service.

Comment: @Saif you can have capacity providers in a cluster that spread the deployments among both Fargate and EC2 instances, so it makes sense to have Fargate services associated with a cluster. Plus there are some cluster-level settings, like logging, that apply to Fargate services.